# bash: patsubst: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux

I'm trying to run `patsubst` in Arch Linux but I get the following:

```
bash: patsubst: command not found
```

Obviously some package has not been installed. So which package belongs `patsubst` to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there is patsubst executable? It seems there is patsubst function in GNU make

Comment: Yes. It is a GNU make function. How can I mark the problem as solved or I have to delete it?